# Windows 8 fresh install

Tags: windows, windows-8, configuration-files

I have recently got the Samsung series 7 ultra laptop and found a  lot of bulkware with the pre-installed windows 8 so I did a fresh install of Windows 8. It went through successfully but I noticed my folder like Documents, Music, Pictures etc. now have "Configuration settings (.ini)" type files named: "desktop". 
(desktop file from Document folder).

When open with notepad, I get something like:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-112
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235
```

What are these for and is it safe to delete?

Comment: already answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/27990/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-desktop-ini-file-in-windows-and-how-can-i-keep-it-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This .ini file stores customizations that you've set for that particular folder, such as icon size, layout, etc.

If you haven't set any customizations these should just be the default settings.  You can delete them if you want, but they'll probably just come back.  They also should only show up if you have the 'show hidden files and folders' option selected under 'folder options.'  That's because Microsoft doesn't think you need to worry about it, which in terms of this particular file is probably true.  The files sizes are negligible and deleting them will only reset any customizations you may have set.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're quite welcome.